# Cant control api json format , text or video result?

Tags: python, api, twitter, flask-restful

```
CONSUMER_KEY = "*******"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "***"
ACCESS_KEY = "**"
ACCESS_SECRET = ****"

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
auth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
requests.get(url, auth=auth)    



r = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=coderFord&count=2',auth=auth)
    res=r.json()


def id_al(): 
    for item in res:
        b=item['id']
        print(b)
        req_ya(b)


def req_ya(b):

    params = {"ids": b}         
    ponse = requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/labs/1/tweets/metrics/private", params=params,auth=auth)
    ak=ponse.json()
    for itema in ak['data']:
        for items in res:    
            k=itema['tweet'] 
            p=itema['video']
            data = {"created_at":items['created_at'],"text":items['text'],"tweet_id": itema['tweet_id'], "like_count": k['like_count'],"retweet_count": k['retweet_count'],"quote_count": k['quote_count'],"reply_count": k['reply_count'],"impression_count": k['impression_count'],"view_count":p['view_count']}
            data_dict = json.dumps(data, indent = 4, sort_keys = True)
            print(json.loads(data_dict))
            collection.insert_one(data)
print(id_al())
```

**Error: KeyError: 'video'**

If the tweet I send is text, it doesn't send me the video view. And it gives an error.How can I control this

And I can't check because the type part of the tweet doesn't exist.

**Response sample like this**

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweet-metrics/quick-start/get-tweets-metrics-private

Comment: You can first check there is `video` in `itema.keys()` and then perform your logic inside this condition.

Comment: I wrote but not working:

Comment: for items in res:    
            if itema['video']==None:
                print("yes")
            else:
                print("no")

Comment: I have posted the same comment as an answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check there is `'video' in itema.keys()` and then perform your logic inside this condition.

Replace this part,

```
for itema in ak['data']:
    for items in res:    
        k=itema['tweet'] 
        p=itema['video'] # here you are getting error.
```

with

```
for itema in ak['data']:
    for items in res:    
        k=itema['tweet'] 
        if 'video' in itema.keys():
            p = itema['video']
```

Comment: @rabianural This will resolve `KerError 'video'`. There should be other issue. What is *not working..* ?